# Add dictionary to embedded dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an embedded dictionary created as:

```
all_stats = {}
all_stats['user1'] = {}
```

I first add an entry with:

```
all_stats['stat0'] = 1
```

I then have a dictionary of each additional entries that will be added to `all_stats` for that user:

```
user_stats = {'stat1':5, 'stat2':3}
```

How can I add these to the embedded dictionary, so I end up with:

```
print(all_stats)
{'user1': {'stat0:1', 'stat1':5, 'stat2':3}}
```

I've tried:

```
all_stats['user1'].update(k=v for k,v in user_stats.items())
```

but this throws a `SyntaxError`

Comment: The syntax error you are facing is `k=v`, it should be `k:v`. However, you don't need to be doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the for loop; you can update one dictionary with another dictionary directly:

```
all_stats['user1']['stat0'] = 1    
all_stats['user1'].update(user_stats)

all_stats
# {'user1': {'stat0': 1, 'stat1': 5, 'stat2': 3}}
```

As for the `Syntax Error`, as commented by @idjaw, you can't use `k=v` in a comprehension in the way you've used; Something similar but acceptable would be:

```
all_stats['user1'].update({k:v for k,v in user_stats.items()})
```

Comment: Thanks! That was easy!

Comment: I don't suppose there's any advantage to the list comprehension version, is there?

Comment: I don't think so. The update method is built to accept a dictionary. From the docs: *Update D from dict/iterable E and F.*. So I guess it should be preferred unless it can't meet what you need. Besides by using the dictionary comprehension, you actually rebuild the dictionary once.